# If energon cubes could be created from any enery source (like oil, magma, etc.) why were Predacons in Beast Wars craving energon crystals?

Tags: transformers

Not sure how much Transformers G1 and Beast Wars continuities intertwine each other, but in G1 we see Transformers creating energon cubes from oil, electricity, magma, etc., it looked like they relatively easy could create energon, however in Beast Wars Predacons are craving for energon crystals, to win a war or something. Why is this so?

If energon cubes could be created from any enery source (like oil, magma, etc.) why were Predacons in Beast Wars craving energon crystals?

Comment: "*Not sure how much Transformers G1 and Beast Wars continuities intertwine each other*" - And there's your answer. They're not consistent with each other

Comment: The wiki entries seem to indicate that the Predacons and Maximals are never shown actually needing to ingest energon, possibly because Earth is so infused by the energy of the crystals. Thus, use of the unusually energon crystals was focused on development of new abilities and technologies. I don't think we see any indication of energon cubes, which could be formed from other Earth energies, doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the G1 cartoon continuity, the Transformers use energon cubes to power themselves, to power weapons, and for trade. As a non-pure form of energon, it's usually only useful to provide power (although there are cases of "impure" energon leaving Transformers disabled after a short period of time, and some formulations (noted to be more pure) did add additional power. In comparison, pure energon, or energon crystals, seems to have additional effects, not only boosting Transformer power, but sometimes transforming them.

Within the *Beast Wars* continuity, they discover that Earth has plentiful energon crystals, to the point that there is stray energon in the air, and they have to use their beast forms to avoid being overloaded. Here, there is little to no need to use the energon just to power themselves, as this happens through ambient energy, so instead the focus is on using this purer energon for military purposes, namely to develop better weapons and to further transform themselves.

### TL;DR

In *Beast War* they didn't need energon cubes to power themselves, but the crystals had additional uses for which they were sought.